# Doctrine ODM query return null result in zf2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

I make a controller action in which I used doctrine query for getting result but when I view result it show `null`.how I set the query of `Doctrine ODM`?
here is my code:

```
 public function indexAction()
    {           
        $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
        $calendars = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Calendar\Document\Calendar')->getQuery()->execute();
    }
```

when I run

```
<?php var_dump($this->calendars); ?>
```

in `.phtml` it retruns `null`, how I get the query result in .phtml?

Comment: Dude can you please STOP creating a new question every hour for the same problem? You have the answer IN ALL THREE THREADS, if calendars is null then your query is wrong and doesn't return ANY DATA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should return the variable `$calendars` in a `ViewModel` in your `indexAction`. Try this :

```
public function indexAction()
{           
    $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
    $calendars = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Calendar\Document\Calendar')->getQuery()->execute();


    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('calendars'=>$calendars));
    return $viewModel;
}
```